# Delphi gridpanel check if cell is empty

Tags: delphi, gridpanel

I want to check if a cell in a gridpanel is empty or not by using the row and column value of that cell.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can test if a specific cell has a control or not by querying the control item of that cell in the `ControlCollection` collection.

```
if Assigned(MyGridPanel.ControlCollection.ControlItems[x, y]) and 
    Assigned(MyGridPanel.ControlCollection.ControlItems[x, y].Control) then
```

Comment: I get the 'Operator not applicable to this operand' error when I add the first assign. With only the second one it gives me a access violation when the cell is empty. When the cell is filled it works. Thanks, I'm way closer now making this work now.

Comment: Never mind, I forgot the end bracket. Getting sleepy here:)